# Error creating a scratch org: This command requires a dev hub org username set either with a flag or by default in the config

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, cicd, sfdx-error

When creating a scratch org, I have this issue that works fine running on my local machine but not when I include in our scripts to run in the CI/CD.

```
ERROR running force:org:create:  This command requires a dev hub org username set either with a flag or by default in the config.
```

To replicate the steps, here's my command to authenticate user works fine:

`sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid 3xxx.lSxxx.7Adxxx --jwtkeyfile assets/server.key --username test@test.com --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias HubOrg`

which subsequently results to:

`Successfully authorized test@test.com with org ID 00D3jxxx`

then the command line that displays the above error is:
`sfdx force:org:create --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json --setdefaultusername --setalias ScratchOrg --wait 10 --durationdays 1`

In troubleshooting, I tried to use `sfdx force:config:list` and displayed only:

```
 Name                  Value  Location 
 ───────────────────── ────── ──────── 
 defaultdevhubusername HubOrg Local
```

There were suggestions from discord channel to remove `alias` and use the working `username`, however, when I try to set the username with this command: `sfdx config:set defaultusername=test@test.com`, I get an error:

```
ERROR running config:set:  No authorization information found for test@test.com.
```

I tried using `sfdx config:set defaultusername=HubOrg` and `sfdx config:set defaultusername=ScratchOrg` but same issue as above.

As mentioned, I tried running this on my MacOS and works fine. Doing my head in why it won't work on our CI server.

---

**Original code:**

I use Makefile to run the commands:
`docker-compose.yml` file:

```
  salesforce:
    image: salesforce/salesforcedx:latest-rc-slim
    working_dir: /work
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash -c'
    volumes:
      - ../:/work
    env_file:
      - .env
```

called by `Makefile`:

```
salesforce: .env
    docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml pull salesforce
    docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "sfdx --version && sfdx plugins --core"
    docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -base64 -K $(DECRYPTION_KEY) -iv $(DECRYPTION_IV)"
# Authorize Dev Hub
    docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $(CONSUMER_KEY) --jwtkeyfile assets/server.key --username $(USER_NAME) --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias HubOrg"
    docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "sfdx force:config:list"
# Create scratch org
    docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "sfdx force:org:create --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json --setdefaultusername --setalias ciorg --wait 10 --durationdays 1"
#   docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "sfdx force:org:create --targetdevhubusername HubOrg --setdefaultusername --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json --setalias ciorg --wait 10 --durationdays 1"
#   this shows error in CI: ERROR running force:org:create:  This command requires a dev hub org username set either with a flag or by default in the config.
#   docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "sfdx force:org:create --targetdevhubusername HubOrg --setdefaultusername --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json --setalias ciorg --wait 10 --durationdays 1"
# # Deploy source to scratch org and run unit tests
#   docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "sfdx force:source:deploy -p 'our-sf-core' -u ciorg -c"
# # Delete scratch org
#   docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "sfdx force:org:delete --targetusername ciorg --noprompt"
.PHONY: salesforce
```

Note: `DECRYPTION_KEY`, `DECRYPTION_IV`, `CONSUMER_KEY`, and `USER_NAME` are included as part of CI variables.

called by `pipeline.yml`:

```
steps:
  - label: ':salesforce: Run Salesforce'
    command:
    - make salesforce
```

I already did the following locally (but understandably, it can't be done via CI):
`sfdx force:auth:web:login --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias HubOrg --instanceurl https://oursalesforcewithdevhub.my.salesforce.com`

---

**Updated files based on David's recommendation**:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
  salesforce:
    image: salesforce/salesforcedx:latest-rc-slim
    working_dir: /.sfdx
    entrypoint: sh
    command: -c "chmod +x ./salesforce.sh && ./salesforce.sh"
    volumes:
      - ./:/.sfdx
    env_file:
      - .env
```

`Makefile`:

```
salesforce: .env
    mkdir ~/.sfdx
    openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -base64 -K $(DECRYPTION_KEY) -iv $(DECRYPTION_IV)
    docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce
```

`salesforce.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

export PATH=~/sfdx/bin:$PATH

sfdx --version && sfdx plugins --core

# Authorize Dev Hub
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid ${CONSUMER_KEY} --jwtkeyfile assets/server.key --username ${USER_NAME} --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias HubOrg
# This is where the error ERROR running auth:jwt:grant:  Unexpected argument: assets/server.key occurs even if I change the sub-directory to .sfdx
```

**Final configuration that worked:**

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```
  salesforce:
    image: salesforce/salesforcedx:latest-rc-slim
    working_dir: /sfdx
    entrypoint: sh
    command: -c "chmod +x ./salesforce.sh && ./salesforce.sh"
    volumes:
      - ../:/sfdx
    env_file:
      - .env
```

running the `salesforce.sh` (as indicated in the `command` above):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

export PATH=~/sfdx/bin:$PATH

sfdx --version && sfdx plugins --core

# Authorize Dev Hub
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant \
--clientid ${CONSUMER_KEY} \
--jwtkeyfile assets/server.key \
--username ${USER_NAME} \
--setdefaultdevhubusername \
--setalias HubOrg

# Create scratch org
sfdx force:org:create --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json --setdefaultusername --setalias ciorg --wait 10 --durationdays 1

# Deploy source to scratch org and run unit tests
sfdx force:source:deploy -p our-sf-core -u ciorg -l RunAllTestsInOrg -c

# Delete scratch org
sfdx force:org:delete --targetusername ciorg --noprompt
```

called by `Makefile`:

```
salesforce: .env
    openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -base64 -K $(DECRYPTION_KEY) -iv $(DECRYPTION_IV)
    docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running all of these commands in a context (within your CI system) that share a persistent filesystem? The behavior you're describing would make perfect sense if your scripts ran in isolated contexts.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed for your swift response. I'm actually using `docker-compose` for the commands as installing directly the sfdx package on CI gives me an issue (but that's another issue that has something to do with incompatibility of GLIB with the OS used by CI). Sample command is `docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml pull salesforce` then `docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "sfdx --version && sfdx plugins --core"` then the commands above

Comment: Please [edit] your post to share some additional details - the compose file, for example, and at least the initial setup command plus the command that produces a failure.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed I have updated the post with full snippets which I hope is enough to help you find the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipeline isn't persisting the location where SFDX stores authentication details, and each command is running in a completely separate container.

```
salesforce: .env
    docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml pull salesforce
    docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "sfdx --version && sfdx plugins --core"
    docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -base64 -K $(DECRYPTION_KEY) -iv $(DECRYPTION_IV)"
# Authorize Dev Hub
    docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $(CONSUMER_KEY) --jwtkeyfile assets/server.key --username $(USER_NAME) --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias HubOrg"
    docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "sfdx force:config:list"
# Create scratch org
    docker-compose -f $(PATH_DEPLOY)/docker-compose.yml run --rm salesforce "sfdx force:org:create --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json --setdefaultusername --setalias ciorg --wait 10 --durationdays 1"
```

Because you're using `docker-compose run --rm`, every one of these commands runs in an isolated container, with no access to the filesystem of the previous container.

You use a volume mount in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
    volumes:
      - ../:/work
```

but it's in the wrong place. You're not persisting any data in `/work` inside the container. `sfdx` stores its authenticated orgs in `~/.sfdx`, which is being discarded each time you run a command and then destroy the container.

You could fix your volume mount, but more broadly, I'm bemused why you're running a bunch of individual commands in separate containers. Just write a shell script and run it in *one* container, so all of your operations share state.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed for the guidance. My unfamiliarity with docker clearly showed up in this instance. I will try to update my code and upvote your answer if works well.

Comment: So I updated my `docker-compose.yaml` file with `working_dir: /.sfdx`, `volumes: - ./:/.sfdx` and `command: -c "./salesforce.sh"` to include everything in a shell script. Now, I get `ERROR running auth:jwt:grant:  Unexpected argument: assets/server.key` or an error where the file doesn't exist if I change it to `.sfdx/server.key` (even if I have the pre-command `mkdir ~/.sfdx` too)

Comment: I've included the updated codes in my post above. It might be another silly take on directories.

Comment: Well, important to note that `~/.sfdx` != `/.sfdx`. That directory isn't where your server key should go, either.

Comment: Thanks David, sorry for the silly ask again on docker but I tried changing the `working_dir` and `volumes` to `~/.sfdx` and it says it needs to be an absolute path. I know I've been a pest but would you be able to check the latest changes on my post above and see if you can easily spot something wrong?

Comment: Don't worry about it, David. It's more on an issue with the shell script accepting the CI variable parameter. I tried hard-coding with actual values and works well. I will update my post with the working solution. Thanks for the guide so far.

Comment: I'm so close now but feels like stuck again. So I was able to create a scratch org. but my next step in running unit tests fail again. My command: `sfdx force:source:deploy -p sfpackage -u ciorg -c` displays this error: `ERROR running force:source:deploy:  This directory does not contain a valid Salesforce DX project.` my working directory is `/.sfdx` with path set to `export PATH=~/sfdx/bin:$PATH`. I've tested the sfpackage directly in local machine and works fine and can run the unit tests

Comment: Why is your working directory `/.sfdx`? That directory is probably empty. You need to be very careful with your volumes, mounts, and environment setup to get Docker to be effective for you.

Comment: I've worked it out based on your suggestions @DavidReed. Thanks. I've updated my original post with the working solution too.